# jQuery Remove Multiple Objects from Array Based On Another Array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array, which contains a list of names. If those names match a key/value pair in another array, I'd like to remove the object containing the match and return the array without that object.

Here's what I have so far as an example:

```
var supervisorsToRemove = ["Supervisor1", "Supervisor2"];
var data = [{id: "Name1", supervisor: "Supervisor1"},{id: "Name2", supervisor: "Supervisor1"},{id: "Name3", supervisor: "Supervisor2"},{id: "Name4", supervisor: "Supervisor3"}]
```

I'd like the resulting data array to be:

```
data = [{id: "Name4", supervisor: "Supervisor3"}]
```

I can remove one supervisor's objects with the following:

```
var supervisorsToRemove = "Supervisor1";
data = $.grep(data, function(e){ 
     return e.supervisor != supervisorsToRemove; 
});
```

But when I try to remove all in the array, it doesn't work:

```
var supervisorsToRemove = ["Supervisor1","Supervisor2"];
data = $.grep(data, function(e){ 
     return e.supervisor != supervisorsToRemove; 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method(or [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method) to check element present in an array

```
data = $.grep(data, function(e){ 
  return supervisorsToRemove.indexOf(e.supervisor) == -1; 
  // or return supervisorsToRemove.includes(e.supervisor); 
});
```

```js
var supervisorsToRemove = ["Supervisor1", "Supervisor2"];
var data = [{
  id: "Name1",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name2",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name3",
  supervisor: "Supervisor2"
}, {
  id: "Name4",
  supervisor: "Supervisor3"
}]
console.log($.grep(data, function(e) {
  return supervisorsToRemove.indexOf(e.supervisor) == -1;
  // or return supervisorsToRemove.includes(e.supervisor); 
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

A better approach would be using an object which holds the supervisor value as property, that would help to make it faster since [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method is slower one.

```
var supervisorsToRemove = {"Supervisor1" : true, "Supervisor2" : true };

data = $.grep(data, function(e){ 
  return !supervisorsToRemove[e.supervisor]; 
});
```

```js
var data = [{
  id: "Name1",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name2",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name3",
  supervisor: "Supervisor2"
}, {
  id: "Name4",
  supervisor: "Supervisor3"
}]
var supervisorsToRemove = {
  "Supervisor1": true,
  "Supervisor2": true
};

console.log(
  $.grep(data, function(e) {
    return !supervisorsToRemove[e.supervisor];
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In case you don't have control over the array then generate the object using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
var obj = supervisorsToRemove.reduce(function(obj, v){ obj[v] = true; return obj; }, {});

data = $.grep(data, function(e){ 
  return !obj[e.supervisor]; 
});
```

```js
var supervisorsToRemove = ["Supervisor1", "Supervisor2"];
var data = [{
  id: "Name1",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name2",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name3",
  supervisor: "Supervisor2"
}, {
  id: "Name4",
  supervisor: "Supervisor3"
}]
var supervisorsToRemove = {
  "Supervisor1": true,
  "Supervisor2": true
};


var obj = supervisorsToRemove.reduce(function(obj, v) {
  obj[v] = true;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(
  $.grep(data, function(e) {
    return !obj[e.supervisor];
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

You can even use native Javascript [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

```js
var supervisorsToRemove = ["Supervisor1", "Supervisor2"];
var data = [{
  id: "Name1",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name2",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name3",
  supervisor: "Supervisor2"
}, {
  id: "Name4",
  supervisor: "Supervisor3"
}]
var supervisorsToRemove = {
  "Supervisor1": true,
  "Supervisor2": true
};

console.log(
  data.filter(function(e) {
    return !supervisorsToRemove[e.supervisor];
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you, your first example worked perfectly. Thanks for the suggestion on improvement, I'm still learning and that helps. 

I create the "supervisorsToRemove" by comparing two arrays like so:

`var allNames = ["Supervisor1","Supervisor2","Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4"];

var allSupervisors = ["Supervisor1","Supervisor2", "Supervisor3"];

var supervisorsToRemove = allSupervisors.filter(i => allNames.indexOf(i) == -1);`

How would I go about changing the result to an object as you suggest to speed it up?

Comment: @troyrmeyer : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In any reasonably-modern browser, no jQuery is needed. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will do the job.

```js
var supervisorsToRemove = ["Supervisor1", "Supervisor2"];
var data = [{
  id: "Name1",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name2",
  supervisor: "Supervisor1"
}, {
  id: "Name3",
  supervisor: "Supervisor2"
}, {
  id: "Name4",
  supervisor: "Supervisor3"
}]


var results = data.filter(function(o) {
  return (supervisorsToRemove.indexOf(o.supervisor) < 0);
});

console.log(results);
```